# SQL INSERT INTO with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, insert, left-join

I'm trying to come up with a MySQL query that will insert data in a table with data from a other table.

That's my structure:

table1:

`ID`   `killerid`     `playerid`     `weapon`

table2:

`ID`     `playername`

Now I want to insert into `table1` in collumn `killerid` and `playerid` the IDs of the two names in a where clause.

But it won't work..

```
INSERT INTO table1 (killerid)
SELECT
    t1.id
FROM
    table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
    table2 t2 ON (t2.killerid = t1.id)
WHERE t2.playername = 'example'
```

**Better to understand:**

I hope thats a little bit better to understand:

There is my table `USERS`

```
ID   |   playername [...]
-----|-------------------
1    |   example1
2    |   example2
```

And there is my table `KILLS`

```
ID   |  killerid  |  victimid  |  weapon
-----|----------------------------------
 1   |    1       |     2      |   FIST
 2   |    2       |     1      |   PISTOL
```

I want to insert into `KILLERS` the IDs of the killer (`killerid`) and the victim (`victimid`) but I only have the 2 names (example1 and example2) when I'm inserting.

So I have to get the IDs of that 2 names in my table `USERS`.

Like (pseudo example):

```
INSERT INTO `KILLERS`(`killerid`, `victimid`, `weapon`)
VALUES(
  USERS.ID WHERE USERS.playername = 'example1',
  USERS.ID WHERE USERS.playername = 'example2',
  'FIST'
 );
```

That should be insert following:

```
ID   |  killerid  |  victimid  |  weapon
-----|----------------------------------
 1   |    1       |     2      |   FIST
```

I hope that's clear.

Comment: whats the error?????????????

Comment: There's no error, it inserts only the killderid and I dont know how to insert killerid, playerid and weapon.

But when I have 4 rows in table2 it inserts 8 rows, when I have 8 it inserts 16 and so on..

Comment: and why do you use Table1 and Table2 in your question but your example uses diff... did you intend to make this question overly difficult to solve?

Comment: sorry, I have completely forgotten that. It's changed.

Comment: You're inserting `killerid`. Where are `playerid` and `weapon` supposed to come from? When the `INSERT` is performed you should be supplying all the columns or later you'll need to go back and `UPDATE` the row you'd inserted earlier, which I suspect isn't what you want to do. So we're back to "where do `playerid` and `weapon` come from?".

Comment: I'm sorry for that. `playerid`and `weapon` comes from table1..

Comment: Just a side note - it would be helpful if you'd using meaningful table names such as `KILLER` and `PLAYER`, instead of `table1` and `table2`. In addition, always use the same name for the same data wherever it's used - thus instead of `table1.id` use `KILLER.KILLERID`; likewise, instead of `table2.id` use `PLAYER.PLAYERID`. This would make things much easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing it better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the data you've got it looks like you can get part way there as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table2(killerid, playerid, weapon)
  SELECT t1.id as killerid,  -- the 'as killerid' is not required but is useful 
         t1.playerid,        -- to help understand what's intended
         t1.weapon
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
      ON t2.killerid = t1.id
    WHERE t2.playername = 'example'
```

### EDIT

Now that we've got a table structure the solution is much easier to figure out.

```
INSERT INTO kills (killerid, victimid, weapon)
  SELECT u1.ID as killerid,
             u2.ID as victimid,
             d.weapon
    FROM USERS u1
    INNER JOIN USERS u2
      ON 1 = 1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT 'FIST' as weapon
                  FROM DUAL) d
      ON 1 = 1
    WHERE u1.playername = 'example1' AND
          u2.playername = 'example2';
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21e91/1)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks! `playerid` is in `table1`.
I need to insert playerid too

Comment: Take a look now. Hopefully that will get you what you needed. Best of luck.

Comment: I just went back and looked at your question, where you say you want to insert into `table1(killerid, playerid)`, but your SQL reads "INSERT INTO **table2**". So which table are you trying to insert into???

Comment: I have a `ID`, a `killerid`and a `playerid` and a `weapon` in my `table1`.

And in `table2` I have a `ID`, a `playername`.

Now I'm trying to insert into my `table1`.

Assuming in `table2` is following row:

`ID`is 1 and `playername` is example.

And I want to insert into `table1`. For example that a player(`playerid`) has been killed by another player(`killerid`) with a weapon(`weapon`).

I need the join to get the ID of the player and the killer.

Is it better to understand?

Comment: I have added a better example in my first post.

Comment: Thanks. That's the solution.
You helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

your sql says:

you need have in varo_lastkills table some values like varo_users table, if you don't have congruent values your query don't run